# Should developers trying to utilize the best of jQuery still be using ThickBox 3.1

Tags: jquery, thickbox

Is this still the recommended library in use? ThickBox 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your concrete needs, but as far as I'm concerned, I was mostly unhappy with it, found the code to be poorly written (at least wrt/ the available jQuery plugin API), and would not recommand it. I'm currently testing nyroModal, and while it's a bit on the heavyweight side, it looks much more promising. But YMMV of course...

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [BlockUI](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/), but other people seem to like [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/)

Comment: I had a look at BlockUI, but I think nyroModal is far better

Comment: I also looked at jqModal, and its interesting, but nyroModal seems better polished

Comment: I also used jqModal on a project, and had to first rewrite it all (using meaningfull names and correct formating) to be able to understand how it worked, then write a non-trivial wrapper around it to make it work with multiforms (think "wizards" and such things), history etc. I ended up with a working solution, but was not really pleased with the resulting kind of mess... Not that jqModal is bad, but was probably not the best fit for my needs.